# How to troubleshoot a mongoose object save?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a node.js api built out that updates a subdocument.  Below is the post call for the subdocument:

```
.put(function(req, res) {
  member.findById(req.params.member_id, function(err, member) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);

    console.log("old: " + member);

    member.address[req.params.address_id].address_type = req.body.address_type;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].street1 = req.body.street1;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].street2 = req.body.street2;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].City = req.body.City;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].State = req.body.State;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].Zip = req.body.Zip;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].Lat = req.body.Lat;
    member.address[req.params.address_id].Lng = req.body.Lng;

    console.log("new:  " + member);

    member.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json({message:'Address Updated!!!'});
    })
  })
})
```

The two console.log lines prove that the object was found in the findById call, then updated after going through the array.  The logs prove that the object in memory is in fact updated.

However, when actioning the `.save()` call, I get the success message, but nothing changes in mongodb.

I get no errors, no warnings, nothing.  It says success, but no change.
How do I troubleshoot?

here's my Address Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema

var AddressSchema = Schema({
  Address_type : String,
  street1 : String,
  street2 : String,
  City : String,
  State : String,
  Zip : Number,
  Lat : Number,
  Lng : Number
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);
```

and here's the parent model, member:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema

var Address = require('./address');
var Award = require('./award');

var MemberSchema = Schema({
  FName : String,
  LName : String,
  address: [Address.Schema],
  phone : {
    type : String,
    number : String
  },
  email: String,
  gender: String,
  DOB: Date,
  rank : {
    level : String,
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  },
  Awards : {
    personal : Boolean,
    award : [Award.Schema],
    granted: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', MemberSchema);
```

Comment: Is `req.params.address_id` an ObjectId or the index of the `address` element to update?

Comment: FWIW, your error handling is off: you call `res.send(err)` in case of errors but your callback function continues to run after that. You need to return from the callback in that case: `if (err) return res.send(err)`.

Comment: Hi JohnnyHK, it is a index to the adderss element.  I want to use ObjectID, but don't know how.

Comment: Thank you.  That was a problem, but when I ran it again, same symptom.

Comment: To JohnnyHK, I am using indexes because I could not figure out how to use objectid's.  I am willing to use either of it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update an array element of a Mongoose document via its index it doesn't trigger the change detection of the array so Mongoose doesn't know to save it (see the [FAQ](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html)).

To manually trigger the change detection, you can call [`markModified`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified) before your call to `member.save`:

```
member.markModified('address');
```

To help troubleshoot these types of problems, enable Mongoose's debug output to see the actual calls it's making to the native driver by adding the following to your startup code:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

Comment: does this replace member.save? or do I put this prior to member.save?

Comment: Put it prior to the `member.save` call.